# Where can I see a treemap of all the Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, stackexchange.com, traffic

I remember seeing a [treemap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) of all the Stack Exchange websites at some point, where each site was represented by a box, on a grid, with the size of the box representing the amount of traffic it got. But I can't find it anymore.

There is an [all sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic) listing, but it's not represented as a treemap.

Can anyone provide the treemap URL, if it's still available? If not, what happened to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close; it's https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid - you can get there by clicking the grid icon:

[image]

That will give you the treemap you're looking for, though it has only two sizes plus an oversized box for Stack Overflow:

[image]